# How to use app.js variables in all routes file?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

How to use `clients` variable in routes/index.js files.

here is my code,

**app.js**

```
clients = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints:[config.contactPoints], keyspace: config.keyspace,authProvider: new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider(config.userName, config.password)});
```

Comment: Is this an Express application?

Comment: Yes this is express application @ImClarky

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method in index.js, export it and pass clients as a parameter to the created method.

In index.js

```
var clients;

exports.assignVal = function(clients){
    this.clients = clients;
};
```

In app.js

```
routes = require('./index');
routes.assignVal(clients);
```

Comment: Thanks i tried your code but its return error like TypeError: routes.assignVal is not a function

Answer (score 0):

If you want this variable to be scoped for each request separatly you can use [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals), in other case you can use [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals)

Comment: Thanks for this but it will more help full if you give direct solution rather than document because i am new in node js.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your router files slightly to pass in a parameter. Like so:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

module.exports = function(your variable) {
  // router.get(...) etc.

  return router
}
```

Then in `app.js`, when you `require` your routers:

```
var index = require('./routes/index')(your variable)
```

Obviously, make sure that your variable is defined before requiring your routers.

Comment: Thanks i tried your code but its return error like TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined in app.js